# Need to connect Windows 10 PC to wired LAN but block internet. Internet through wireless

Tags: windows, networking, routing, lan, ipconfig

Is there a rather straightforward way to allow a specific Windows 10 PC on a LAN network to access LAN resources through ethernet, but allow internet only through wirelessly connected to an access point on another network?

This is for a home networking project.

I am trying to manage data under my 1TB monthly cap on my Comcrap internet. I have access to free public wifi, but it's very slow (like 25 Mbps down / 10 Mbps up realistic speeds if it's a good day), but it's OK for transferring backup data or downloading things like Steam games that can suck up data quickly.

In any case, I have an older laptop that I was planning to repurpose for this. So I can download the data from the public wi-fi and access it over my LAN.

My modem is a Netgear Orbi.

Here's my IPCONFIG info for the wired and wireless devices as well as ROUTE PRINT

**IPCONFIG WIRED ETHERNET (LAN):**

[image: IPCONFIG WIRED ETHERNET]

**IPCONFIG WIRELESS (INTERNET):**

[image: IPCONFIG WIRELESS (INTERNET)]

**ROUTE PRINT:**

[image: ROUTE PRINT]

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured out how to do it from Windows command prompt using nifty command `netsh`. Thanks to user 'Andy Shinn' for pointing me in the right direction. This may be elementary stuff to you network wizards, but for a nub like me, it's rocket science lol:

- I set static IP for the device in my router for good measure (i.e. 192.168.1.10)
- `ipconfig /all` to confirm IP/subnet (i.e. 192.168.1.10 / 255.255.255.0)
- `netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces` and note the device "Name" (i.e. "Ethernet")
- `netsh interface ipv4 set address "Ethernet" static 192.168.1.10 255.255.255.0 none` ('none' removes gateway)

BAM! No internet through wired LAN, but still have access over LAN. I can connect to wireless and have internet that way.

To reset gateway back to DHCP:

`netsh interface ipv4 set address "Ethernet" dhcp`

Answer (score 0):

The default gateway (route to 0.0.0.0) is your Internet path. As you outlined, you have two (one through wireless and one wired). The wired is preferred in this case because of the lower metric (it prefers routes with lower metric).

One idea might be to use a program to set profiles for your wired connection to set a static IP address with and without a gateway. A program such as https://github.com/KurtisLiggett/Simple-IP-Config could do this. There may be others but this was first in my searching.

- When you want the computer to use the wired connection for the internet, choose the profile that has the gateway.
- When you want to use the wireless, choose the profile that has the gateway removed from the wired connection.

I have not tried this personally. I am just thinking of a way to solve it at the networking level.

Comment: Thanks. But isn't there away to have BOTH connected at the same time and have internet access on wireless, while the wired connected to LAN but block it's internet access?

Comment: Removing the gateway will not disconnect it. The gateway is there to provide it access beyond your local network. You should still be able to access addresses on the local subnet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. I'll give it a shot. That program looks pretty useful. Better than me fumbling around with command line route changes (which I'm guaranteed to screw up, lol).